# How to use Arabic text on sqlite db?

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, sqlite, multilingual

In my iPhone application, I want to store and retrieve Arabic, Gujrati languages on sqlite db. Most of them I read is to use unicode for storing & getting data from sqlite db.

```
 How could I accomplish this, could any one instruct me with good tutorial.
```

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 4):

Unicode supports Arabic text. sqlite supports Unicode text using UTF-8 encoding. If you can put your Arabic text in an NSString, you can store it and retrieve it in sqlite. You don't have to do anything special at all.

```
// bind a string into a query
NSString *stringWithArabicText = @" some arabic text ";
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, index, [stringWithArabicText UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

// get a string from a query
char *str = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, index);
NSString *stringWithArabicText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:str];
```

This will work for text in any language supported by Unicode, including Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite database has UTF8 charset, thus:

```
NSString * stringfromdatabase;
const char *cstring = [stringfromdatabase cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSString *utf8string = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:cstring encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",utf8string); // here you will see arabic.
```

You can optimize it, of course.

Answer (score -1):

Dear frind its to easy: just dont use TEXT as a type for your arabic text but use VARCHAR <[Affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)>

means remove TEXT and put VARCHAR instead of it.

[you can visit this sit](https://arabicprogrammer.com/article/1495417658)

Comment: Why? There is no VARCHAR data type in SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Check: (3.1.1. Examples of Affinity Name) on the same page I was referring to  in SQLite: sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Affinity is not the same as data type.

Comment: Thanks for your kind note,I'll try to correct my ansor.